# Convert installed package to shippable RPM centos

Tags: linux, centos

How can i convert metricbeat to a shippable RPM which could be installed by SCP on servers without internet?

How i installed metric beat

```
sudo rpm --import https://packages.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch
```

in /etc/yum.repos.d/elastic.repo add

```
[elastic-7.x]
name=Elastic repository for 7.x packages
baseurl=https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/yum
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch
enabled=1
autorefresh=1
type=rpm-md

Sudo yum install metricbeat
```

How can I make this into a copyable rpm?

Comment: You can download the RPM using `yumdownloader` and use `scp` to copy it to the servers without internet access.

Comment: please put this as an answer, or I will mark my question as duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the RPM using `yumdownloader` and use `scp`, or some other method, to copy it to the servers without internet access.